# How do I define new default task runners in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wrote my own task runner in Vscode. How do I get it to show up in "configure task runners" menu, along with other default task runners? thanks.

Right now ,VsCode shows a list of task runners when trying to run the build command without a configured task runner. When I define my own I have to copy and paste it with every new project. So to have a way to make it show up in the list of default tasks would be great.

Comment: I think you should make this as a feature request in the [vscode repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues). I couldn't find any task related attributes in `settings.json`. You may want to check out if it's possible with a custom [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview#_extensions).